# ansible copy not working

Tags: ansible

I am not able to copy a file using ansible . I dont even get any error

test-playbook.yml

```
---
- name: Test file
  hosts: development
  tasks:
     name: Copying file
     copy: src=/home/rajesh.devan/ansible_test/Hello.txt dest=/home/rajesh.devan/ansible_test/HelloWorld.txt
```

hosts:

```
 [development]
 dxxxxcorh516.xxxxx.com ansible_user=rajesh.devan
```

When I run:

```
rajesh.devan@dxxxocorh516:~/ansible_test $ ansible-playbook test-playbook.yml --ask-pass
SSH password:

PLAY [Test file] **************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [dxxxxlocorh516.global.xxxxx.com]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
dtxxxxxcorh516.xxxxx.com : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please pay close attention to your playbook syntax.
Your output suggests that there is no task with name "Copying file" executed.
It is because, `tasks:` should be a yaml list, where each new item is started with a dash:

```
---
- name: Test file
  hosts: development
  tasks:
    - name: Copying file
      copy: src=/home/rajesh.devan/ansible_test/Hello.txt dest=/home/rajesh.devan/ansible_test/HelloWorld.txt
```

Comment: I modified my playbook like                                                                             `---
- name: Test file
- hosts: development
- tasks:
   - name: Copying file
   - copy: src=/home/rajesh.devan/ansible_test/Hello.txt dest=/home/rajesh.devan/ansible_test/HelloWorld.txt`
But i end up getting this error `rajesh.devan@dxxxxlocorh516:~/ansible_test $ ansible-playbook test-playbook.yml --ask-pass
SSH password:
ERROR: hosts declaration is required`

Comment: @RajeshDevan I gave you the right syntax. Please see (playbook intro)[http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html] to get the idea where you should put dashes.

Comment: Thanks @Konstantin This page is not available docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html